# Manejo correcto del error al pasar un información incorrecta con Moongose, Express y Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un login en el cual se valida la información entregada por el usuario:

```
app.post("/sessions",function(req,res){

User.findOne({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password},function(err,user){
        req.session.user_id = user._id;
        res.redirect("/app");
    });
});
```

Esta cumple muy bien su tarea de validar al usuario, pero cuando le ingreso un usuario incorrecto recibo en la consola un `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null`
He investigado, pero aun no encuentro como hacerme cargo de el error para que no se muestre en la consola, ya que cada vez que se ejecuta el error, node deja de trabajar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta introducir varios conroles de errores en el flujo

1. existen los datos en input?
2. `findOne` devolvió un error?
3. el `user` existe?

```js
app.post("/sessions",function(req,res) {
  const { email, password } = req.body

  if (!email || !password) {
    // redirect el usuario o envia un mensaje de error
    // falta email o password
    return res.redirect("/login?error=INVALID EMAIL OR PASSWORD")
  }

  User.findOne({email: email, password: password}, function(err, user) {
    if (err || !user) {
      // redirect el usuario...
      // ha occurido un error o el usuario no existe
      return res.redirect("/login?message=INVALID USER")  
    }

    req.session.user_id = user._id
    res.redirect("/app")
  })
})
```